# Shapefiles under 1000 features but ArcGIS Online not accepting it?

Tags: arcgis, shapefile

I have a couple of zipped shapefiles with around 100-150 features. I am trying to add them on ArcGIS Online (which accepts under 1000 features per shapefile) but it is unable to do so, indicating to me that the zipped shapefile is too big.

I am not sure why since the features are way under 1000

Comment: 1) Is there any way you can share the shapefile with us? 2) What is the file size of the zipped shapefile? 3) Can you please post the exact error message you see? 4) Do you have an organizational ("paid") account or a public ("free") account?

Comment: @GaryS. The shapefiles are found here: http://jncc.defra.gov.uk/page-5201&LAYERS=UKCS,MCZ (Under Map Layers, and then under Protected Areas). They are between 20,000 KB and 130,000 KB. I have an organizational account.

Answer (score 1):

You may be encountering a problem with file size and/or other data on your account, rather than the record limit.

> **[How much storage space do I get?](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#anchor38)**
>
> Subscriptions provide flexible storage capacity options for your organization.
> If you have an organizational account, check with your
> administrator for information about your storage limit. If you are an
> administrator, you can view detailed reports about your organization's
> storage of tiles, features, and files. A public account comes with 2
> GB of total storage space.

Also note:

> Organizational and public accounts can upload items through My Content that are up to 1 GB in size. This is a browser limit; larger file sizes may be supported when uploading through desktop applications such as ArcGIS for Desktop.